# insert into table select max(column_name)+1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql table built like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `post_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `post_user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `gen_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`post_user_id`, `post_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

When I do:

```
insert into posts (post_user_id) values (1);
insert into posts (post_user_id) values (1);
insert into posts (post_user_id) values (2);
insert into posts (post_user_id) values (1);
select * from posts;
```

I get:

```
post_id | post_user_id | gen_id
1                  1     0
2                  1     0
1                  2     0
3                  1     0
```

A unique post_id is generated for each unique user.

I need the gen_id column to be 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc. How can I increment this column when I do an insert. I tried the one below, but it won't work. What's the right way to do this?

```
insert into posts (post_user_id,gen_id) values (1,select max(gen_id)+1 from posts);
//Select the highest gen_id and add 1 to it.
```

Comment: post_id gives me an id starting with 1 for each user. Which is why I need a separate column that goes 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc.

Comment: I don't understand. When you want gen_id to be same as post_id, why even bother adding that column?

Comment: I don't want it to be the same as post_id. post_id is 123 for user 1, then again 12345 for user 2. gen_id = 123456789 10 11 12 . It does'nt start from 1 for each user.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
  INSERT INTO posts (post_user_id,gen_id) 
  SELECT 1, MAX(gen_id)+1 FROM posts;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `TRIGGER` on your table.  This sample code can get you started:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ai_trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON posts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    UPDATE posts 
       SET gen_id = (SELECT MAX(gen_id) FROM posts) + 1
     WHERE post_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
     LIMIT 1;

END;//
DELIMITER  ;
```

Comment: Thanks. For me in SQL Server SSMS 2016, I'm getting an intellisense error for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. It says `LAST_INSERT_ID() is not a recognized built in function name`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For my case the first number to increment was null. I resolve with

```
IFNULL(MAX(number), 0) + 1
```

or better the query became

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(number), 0) + 1 FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the table "Autos" and the data that it contains to begin with:

```
AutoID | Year | Make | Model | Color |Seq
1      | 2012 | Jeep |Liberty| Black | 1 
2      | 2013 | BMW  | 330XI | Blue  | 2
```

The `AutoID` column is an auto incrementing column so it is not necessary to include it in the insert statement.

The rest of the columns are varchars except for the `Seq` column which is an integer column/field.

If you want to make it so that when you insert the next row into the table and the `Seq` column auto increments to the # 3 you need to write your query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Autos
(
  Seq,
  Year,  
  Make, 
  Model,
  Color,

)
Values
(
  (SELECT MAX(Seq) FROM Autos) + 1, --this increments the Seq column
  2013,'Mercedes','S550','Black');
```

The reason that I put the `Seq` column first is to ensure that it will work correctly... it does not matter where you put it, but better safe than sorry.

The `Seq` column should now have a value of `3` along with the added values for the rest of that row in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I intended that to be displayed did not happen...so I will start from the beginning:  First I created a table.

```
create table Cars (  
AutoID int identity (1,1) Primary Key,
Year int,
Make varchar (25),
Model varchar (25),
TrimLevel varchar (30),
Color varchar (30),
CreatedDate date,
Seq int
)
```

Secondly I inserted some dummy values

```
insert into Cars values (

2013,'Ford' ,'Explorer','XLT','Brown',GETDATE(),1),
(2011,'Hyundai' ,'Sante Fe','SE','White',GETDATE(),2),
(2009,'Jeep' ,'Liberty','Jet','Blue',GETDATE(),3),
(2005,'BMW' ,'325','','Green',GETDATE(),4),
(2008,'Chevy' ,'HHR','SS','Red',GETDATE(),5);
```

When the insertion is complete you should have 5 rows of data.
Since the Seq column is not an auto increment column and you want to ensure that the next Seq's row of data is automatically incremented to the # 6 and its subsequent rows are incremented as well you would need to write the following code:

```
INSERT INTO Cars
(
  Seq,
  Year,
  color,
  Make,
  Model,
  TrimLevel,
  CreatedDate
)
Values
(
  (SELECT MAX(Seq) FROM Cars) + 1,
  2013,'Black','Mercedes','A550','AMG',GETDATE());
```

I have run this insert statement many times using different data just to make sure that it works correctly....hopefully this helps!