# Why is IFNULL() not working here

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm checking if a column value is blank because I need to add 1 to it. This is actually a follow up of my question here

[My Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282116/insert-into-table-select-maxcolumn-name1/13282214#13282214)

I'm doing

```
INSERT INTO posts (post_user_id, gen_id)  SELECT 1, IFNULL((MAX(gen_id)+1 FROM
posts),0);
```

What's wrong here?

I keep getting some kind of error.

Comment: You have written `IFNULL` instead of `ISNULL`

Comment: Sorry. I corrected that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try substituting it with `COALESCE`

```
INSERT INTO posts (post_user_id, gen_id) 
SELECT 1, COALESCE((MAX(gen_id)+1) ,0) 
FROM posts
```

- [*See SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da0ae/6)

or `IFNULL`

```
INSERT INTO posts (post_user_id, gen_id) 
SELECT 1, IFNULL((MAX(gen_id)+1) ,0) 
FROM posts
```

- [*See SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da0ae/8)

Answer (score 1):

try case

```
INSERT INTO posts (post_user_id, gen_id) values 
SELECT 1,
   case when gen_id IS null then (select MAX(gen_id) from posts)
   else 0 
   end
```